# How to pass an event Handler to a function that adds controls to that handler in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I made a class that handles the display of a set of controls. These controls are created at runtime.  Because of that, I have to add them to an event handler at runtime as well.  I made a function that allows me to specify the event handler to be used for some of the controls. The code looks like this:

Here's the main form

```
Dim displayObj as PackageDisplay = new PackageDisplay(AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged)
```

The constructor does this

```
Public Sub New(ByRef eventHandler as Action(Of System.Object, EventArgs)
    AddHandler chkExample.CheckedChanged, eventHandler
End Sub
```

However, I get the following error:

> Value of type 'System.Action(Of Object, System.EventArgs)' cannot be converted to 'System.EventHandler'

It surely must be possible to pass an event handler and assign it, but I just don't know how.  I've tried several different variations of this, but I can't figure out how to make this work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just pass in an eventhandler delegate instead of an action

Comment: I tried making a delegate, but it said the same basic thing.  I'm not an expert in delegates though, so I'll try that again.

Comment: You don't need to **make** one, use the stock `System.EventHandler`

Comment: Thank you, tcarvin!  *That* was the answer I needed.  Duh! =D

Comment: @tcarvin: Please post your comment as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: That's nifty. I do similar things all the time, but many of my controls raise multiple events I want to subscribe to, so it makes sense just to add the handlers after calling the ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to **make** one, use the stock `System.EventHandler`.